# Google Drive API changes().getStartPageToken returns no changes

Tags: java, google-drive-api

i am following the standard example for Java Google Drive API, retrieving the changes. The weird thing is that when asking for the first page token

```
            StartPageToken response = driveService.changes()
                .getStartPageToken()
                .execute();
```

When loading the changes

```
            ChangeList changes = driveService.changes().list(pageToken)
                .setFields("changes,kind,newStartPageToken,nextPageToken")
                .execute();
```

The changes list is always empty, and the nextPageToken is null...with a 20Gb filled Drive is, at minimum, weird!
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong approach. Downloading a whole drive would be more or less like this

- Retrieve the changes startToken
- Download all data from drive
- Save the startToken
- Load the (eventual changes)

The thing is: take a bookmark, download everything, then start getting changes (starting from the bookmark)

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code you ended up with? I am just looking at this now and am hoping it shows the change that was made? ie. this text changed to this text... Does it do that?